# Class definition

Tags: python-3.x, instantiation, python-class

My questions are the code I am running keeps giving me points has no argument, below is my code, please help check

```
class Point:
    def _init_(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        
    def draw(self):
        print(f"Point ({self.x}, {self.y})")
   

point = Point(1, 2)
point.draw(point)
```

Comment: The first argument of an instance method is always the instance itself. It is always implicitly provided if you run `point.draw()`. This means you do not need to call `point.draw(point)`, because the instance `point` is already given.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: With stackexchange.com, there are [tags](https://stackoverflow.com/tags). No railroad crossings.

Comment: With that line of code above as it is written, it keeps  giving me Name-error, that's Point its not callable